# How can I put elements under inline element?

Tags: html, css, inline

I created a split nav menu using two ul elements so I used inline to get the items horizontal to each other. Now, when I try to add elements under the nav menu, they are inline with it unless I add a bunch of lines.

I can't figure out how to get the layout right while maintaining a horizontal nav bar.

```html
<div class="topnav">
      <ul class="leftnav">
        <li><a href="#home">BRAND</a></li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="rightnav">
        <li><a href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li><a href="#portfolio">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
        <li><a href="#personal">PERSONAL</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    
    <div class="content">
      <hr>
      <p>text</p>

    </div>
  </div>
```

```html
    .topnav li {
      display: inline;
    }
```

https://codepen.io/mishlc/pen/dybwwYW

Comment: Your `.topnav` element has zero height, because all children are floated. Go read up on how clearing floats works. https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/#article-header-id-2

Comment: Ahhhhhh, I'm an idiot thanks

Comment: @agapambor Just a suggestion: Avoid float and inline display. They are not intended for layout and have draw backs. Consider the more modern flex box layout. It's more versatile and has less draw backs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `<div class="clear"></div>` end of the `topnav` div
and add **clear:both** CSS to .clear class

```
body {
   width: 80%;
   margin: auto;
}
.topnav li {
    display: inline;
    font-family: "Alegreya Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.topnav a {
    color: #282828;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.leftnav {
    font-size: 1.4em;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 1em;
    padding-right: 1em;
}
.rightnav {
    font-size: 1em;
    padding-right: 1em;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 1.7em;
}
.rightnav a {
   margin-right: 1em;
}
.rightnav a:hover {
    color: #c71132;
}
.rightnav a.active {
    color: #c71132;
}
.clear{
     clear: both;
}
```

html code

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="topnav">
        <ul class="leftnav">
            <li><a href="#home">BRAND</a></li>
         </ul>
         <ul class="rightnav">
            <li><a href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#portfolio">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
            <li><a href="#personal">PERSONAL</a></li>
          </ul>
         <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <hr>
      <p>text</p>
      <p>text</p>
      <p>text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
/*if you want to show both list in line, otherwise remove it*/
.topnav ul {
  display: inline;
}

.topnav ul li {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav">
      <ul class="leftnav">
        <li><a href="#home">BRAND</a></li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="rightnav">
        <li><a href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li><a href="#portfolio">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
        <li><a href="#personal">PERSONAL</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    
    <div class="content">
      <hr>
      <p>text</p>

    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code and hope this will help you understand that you need not use floats always to make navigation or align things horizontally.

```css
/*body {
   width: 80%;
   margin: auto;
}
.topnav li {
    display: inline;
    font-family: "Alegreya Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.topnav a {
    color: #282828;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.leftnav {
    font-size: 1.4em;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 1em;
    padding-right: 1em;
}
.rightnav {
    font-size: 1em;
    padding-right: 1em;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 1.7em;
}
.rightnav a {
   margin-right: 1em;
}
.rightnav a:hover {
    color: #c71132;
}
.rightnav a.active {
    color: #c71132;
}
.clear{
     clear: both;
}*/

*{box-sizing:border-box;}
body {
   width: 80%;
   margin: auto;
   padding:0;
   margin:0;
}
.topnav{
  font-family: "Alegreya Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  display:block;
  width:100%;
}
.leftnav,.rightnav{
  text-decoration:none;
  list-style-type:none;
  padding:0;margin:0;
}
.leftnav{
  display:inline-block;
  max-width:30%;
  
}
.rightnav{
  display:inline-block;
  max-width:calc(100% - (30% + 30%));
  min-width: calc(100% - (30% + 30%));
  margin-left:30%;
  
}
.leftnav li,.rightnav li{
  display:inline-block;
}
.leftnav li{
  width:100%;
}
.rightnav li{
  width: 32.5%;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0 0.05%;
}
.rightnav a {
   display:block;
   width:100%;
}
.rightnav a:hover {
    color: #c71132;
}
.rightnav a.active {
    color: #c71132;
}
.rightnav a:hover, .rightnav a.active{
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="topnav">
        <ul class="leftnav">
            <li><a href="#home">BRAND</a></li>
         </ul>
         <ul class="rightnav">
            <li><a href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#portfolio">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
            <li><a href="#personal">PERSONAL</a></li>
          </ul>
        <!--  <div class="clear"></div> -->
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <hr>
      <p>text</p>
      <p>text</p>
      <p>text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Your must keep your style in `<style></style>` block. Means, it should be

```
<style>
    .topnav li {
      display: inline;
    }
</style>
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    .topnav li {
  display: inline;
}
  </style>
</head>
<div class="topnav">
      <ul class="leftnav">
        <li><a href="#home">BRAND</a></li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="rightnav">
        <li><a href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li><a href="#portfolio">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
        <li><a href="#personal">PERSONAL</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    
    <div class="content">
      <hr>
      <p>text</p>

    </div>
  
</html>
```

Comment: I'm sorry I should have been more clear, it's a separate css sheet, I just copy pasted the relevant part.

Comment: If it works for you then mark it as the correct answer and vote me.